# Symbolic link ./././

Tags: linux, directory

So I was asked to create a link "..." like ../  but two go an extra level up in Linux. I understand that I must use ln -s to create a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to do the following (if I understood your question correctly):

```
ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink
```

Comment: can you either repeat what you are trying to say or just edit the comment to make it more clear, for some reason (could be totally my fault, sorry for that) I am unable to grasp as to what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok so what I have is say I am in the directory home/zman/it200 and I am told to go back to the home directory I can use ../ but I would need to use twice so instead of doing that I have to create a symbolic link to have that do it twice for me when I call the link, hope this makes more sense?

Comment: sure you can do something like: `ln -s ../../ target` and then if you do `cd target` you will have a link to your home directory.

Comment: very important question, does it import everything from the home library or move to the home library. so what i mean is when i took you advice and did ln -s ../../ target and then did cd target my pwd is /it244/hw2/target , is this right?

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s ../.. ... #target linkName
```

[rtf ln(1) m](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln)